# Are different look and feels able to use different initial component properties?

Tags: java, swing, awt, look-and-feel

When we are creating a component, this component takes some initial values and it will be styled accordingly to the active `Look & Feel`. For example, a `JButton` will start with horizontal alignment equals to 0 (probably `SwingConstants.CENTER`).

My question is, are these look and feels able to "change-override" these initial values of the default components (I am not talking for `NimbusButton extends JButton`). Again, I'm referring only to this kind of properties all components have, and not styles and how they look (even if some of these properties affect the appearance of the component).

I have tested the previous value (`JButton.horizontalAlignment`) with Java's look and feel, my system's look and feel (Windows 10) and Nimbus. The value seems to remain the same. **But what about other LAFs, or other values from other Components?**

One could say, that my question can be experessed also as *"What look and feels are able to change"*?

```
public class LookAndFeels {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            // No look and feel
            System.out.println(new JButton().getHorizontalAlignment());

            // Nimbus
            setNimbusLAF();
            System.out.println(new JButton().getHorizontalAlignment());

            setSystemLAF();
            System.out.println(new JButton().getHorizontalAlignment());
        });
    }

    private static void setSystemLAF() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void setNimbusLAF() {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question can't have a full answer (trust me when i say it's too complicated ,I'm implementing one from scratch and it's 4 month now and i don't even know if I'm close to call it!) .

> My question is, are these look and feels able to "change-override" these initial values of the default components

yes and no,they can change such properties but it's them responsibility to honor'em .
plus most of the initial values are first to show-up look and feel values,  [here this will give you a hint about what happend at your first println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

the real answer will be checking the `ComponentUI` implementation of the one you are asking about  .

you are a coder so it's not a shock for you to find out what they can change is the same as any code out side of it's original package (since code is code!!).

> I have tested the previous value (JButton.horizontalAlignment) with Java's look and feel, my system's look and feel (Windows 10) and Nimbus. The value seems to remain the same. But what about other L&F's, or other values from other Components?

every ui object have a method called `installUI(JComponent c)` this question answer is wrapped around this method , this method is called when you change the ui and depending on the implementation their ,they change some of the properties to fit them need's (E.g take any of the dark L&F's as an example ,them implementation for `AbstractButton` ui will have to set the background to a dark color and the foreground to bright color so the text would appear since they are dark ).

> "What look and feels are able to change"

many people think that the ui control a small bits of the component , but in real it's all from the ui !! for instance `AbstractButton` have text , many people think that the ui  is not responsible to display it but it's other way around !, if the ui didn't call `Graphics.drawString(AbstractButton.getText(),x,y)` (or something equivalent) somewhere in their `paint(Graphics g,JComponent c)` method  no text will be

so the short answer to your question 'every thing on the screen' .